# JSOUP website scraping

Tags: jsoup

How can this link be scraped: https://www.higheredjobs.com/details.cfm?JobCode=176261274&Title=Student%20Services%20Advisor?

It seems that site has a strong protection.
I tried smth like that:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://www.higheredjobs.com/details.cfm?JobCode=176261274")
                .timeout(0) // Relax the server by according it infinite time...
                .maxBodySize(0)
                .header("Accept-Encoding", "gzip")
                .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.94 Safari/537.36")
                .referrer("https://www.higheredjobs.com/details.cfm?JobCode=176261274")
                .cookie("D_HID","/iHO5bR2qxwBL4Zf0KOB6W28KoU9Q4K9/Ou8c5S+V3o")
                .cookie("D_UID","E0FB6547-868C-38AC-BAF2-A752089887E0")
                .cookie("D_IID","915B5DF8-71F1-3991-82F0-ED68EBA81949")
///all other cookies
                .get();
```

but response is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head> 
  <meta name="ROBOTS" content="NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW" /> 
  <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="max-age=0" /> 
  <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" /> 
  <meta http-equiv="expires" content="0" /> 
  <meta http-equiv="expires" content="Tue, 01 Jan 1980 1:00:00 GMT" /> 
  <meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" /> 
  <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="10; url=/distil_r_blocked.html?Ref=/details.cfm?JobCode=176261274&amp;distil_RID=90819EF6-155B-11E6-97F5-80CDFCB63E7D&amp;distil_TID=20160508202929" /> 
  <script type="text/javascript">
    (function(window){
        try {
            if (typeof sessionStorage !== 'undefined'){
                sessionStorage.setItem('distil_referrer', document.referrer);
            }
        } catch (e){}
    })(window);
</script> 
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/ga100524.js" defer=""></script>
  <style type="text/css">#d__fFH{position:absolute;top:-5000px;left:-5000px}#d__fF{font-family:serif;font-size:200px;visibility:hidden}#qczbxvczrsvrrb{display:none!important}</style>
 </head> 
 <body> 
  <div id="distil_ident_block">
   &nbsp;
  </div>   
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? A simple `GET` request gives you the `HTML` of the link. You cannot submit those cookies to to server - how do you know their values when you connect for the first time to the server? You cannot use old values, because the server generates them per session.

Comment: Simple GET gives an empty page. If you open link in a browser it shows something quite different.

Comment: It seems that it's nearly impossible to scrape this website with Jsoup, since it uses [Distill Networks](http://www.distilnetworks.com/) anti-scraping software. (See [here](https://www.quora.com/How-does-distil-networks-bot-and-scraper-detection-work) also). You could try with Selenium or some other library which actually emulates a real browser, but otherwise, I don't know how you could make this work.

Comment: I've just ran your piece of code WITHOUT the cookies and set the referrer to  "https://www.higheredjobs.com" and I've got the full HTML of this page. I've saved it and opend it in my browser, and it's looks OK (accept the missing CSS of course).

Comment: @TDG I think if the piece of code run on a VPS it might not work.

Comment: Yes, it seems that the problem is with VPS usage...
Thank you, TDG.